# initialize itertools count in library from database query

Tags: python, class, instantiation, python-itertools

I have a library which is used by a project I built.  One of the classes in the library uses itertools to generate an incrementing id (currently starting from 1) every time it is instantiated.  I'd like to be able to initialize where the incrementing starts in the library based on ids that are known in the main loop of the server daemon which uses the library.  This is so when I start and stop the daemon, the ids can pick up from where they left off.  The daemon can determine the correct starting point using an SQL query to the db backend, but I can't figure out how to pass it into the library to be used as a starting point.

From the library, currently:

```
class Thing(object):
    id_iter = itertools.count(1)
    def __init__(self):
        self.id = self.id_iter.next()
```

I'd like to replace 1 with a variable that can be passed into the class on its first instantiation.  Any idea how?  A different approach?

Comment: You mean that the first time an instance of the class is created the id is set?

Comment: each time the server starts, it determines that starting point from the db, and I need to pass that value to initialize the starting point of the class iterator (which is in a library)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Thing(object):
    id_iter = None
    def __init__(self, num=1):
        if Thing.id_iter is None:
            Thing.id_iter = itertools.count(num)
        self.id = next(self.id_iter)
```

Example:

```
x = Thing(5)
print(x.id)      #prints 5
y = Thing()
print(y.id)      #prints 6
```

Comment: this still doesn't give me a way to pass the starting point from the server which uses the library. Without that, the iterator just starts back off at 1 when the server is relaunched.  getting the starting point into the library is the main issue.

Comment: @domoarrigato - a bit confused, that's why i included a `num=1` in the `__init__` constructor, when the server is relaunched you can just pass the starting point from the db to the constructor. See my answer for an example.

Comment: ok, got it working.  the problem was that Thing isn't instantiated directly in the daemon, but rather by other classes in the library, so I needed to initialize it by instantiating it directly once when the server loads.  awesome!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [itertools.islice](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) to start (and stop) iterating at arbitrary indices.

```
>>> cycler = itertools.cycle(range(20))
>>> itertools.islice(cycler, 10, None).next()
10
>>> cycler.next()
11
```

How you use it in your specific case depends on the class iterable and how it is instantiated.